# Are these two SQL Server queries the same?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have written two queries for fetching column values that either do not start with vowels or do not end with vowels.

Query 1:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY
FROM STATION
WHERE city NOT LIKE '[aeiou]%'
   OR city NOT LIKE '%[aeiou]'
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY
FROM STATION
WHERE city NOT LIKE '[aeiou]%[aeiou]'
```

According to me, they should be same query as they pass test cases easily and filter same result. Are these two different queries in any scenario?

Answer (score 5):

No, they behave differently. I expected some differences with cities like `"a"`, because a string with length 1 will not match pattern `[aeiou]%[aeiou]`, but may match both `[aeiou]%` and `%[aeiou]`. Just tried it out, and actually there are differences then. One can still discuss which of both queries interpret `'a'` correctly, but at least both queries behave differently:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (VALUES ('aasfa')
             , ('basda')
             , ('asdfb')
             , ('a')
       ) t1 (c)
       where c  not like '[aeiou]%[aeiou]';
```

Result:

```
c
-----
basda
asdfb
a
```

Query:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (VALUES ('aasfa')
             , ('basda')
             , ('asdfb')
             , ('a')
       ) t1 (c)
       where c    not  like '[aeiou]%'
or c not  like '%[aeiou]'
```

Result:

```
c
-----
basda
asdfb
```

Answer (score 2):

No, they are not the same. It can be seen by application of de Morgan's rule:

```
!a or !b = !(a and b),
```

where the events `a` and `b` are given by

```
a = like '[aeiou]%'
b = like '%[aeiou]'.
```

<s>Moreover, `a and b` corresponds to the event `like '[aeiou]%[aeiou]'`, which is basically a set intersection of the two sets containing all events `a` and `b`.</s>

EDIT: The previous sentence is wrong, and it produces wrong results exactly for one-element strings. In order to find the set `a and b`, consider

```
a = { x | first element in {a,e,i,o,u} }
b = { x | last  element in {a,e,i,o,u} }
```

Therefore,

```
a AND b = { x | first AND last element in {a,e,i,o,u} }
```

Now, in contrast, `like '[aeiou]%[aeiou]'` is the subset of `a AND b` that has another optional character between the first and the last element.

Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Yes, I thought same but as pointed out by @Stephan Lechner, I was skeptical, are there any test cases where the queries behave differently.

Comment: @Kajal_T: ok, completely right, they're NOT identical. I'll post the theoretical underpinning (the error was in the last step).

Answer (score 1):

Both these queries fetch cities that have a non-vowel at the beginning or end of their name.  They should return the same result set.  For instance, "Miami" matches both queries.

However, they are not the *same*.  One will execute the underlying `like` operator twice, and the other once.  In this case, the performance difference is likely to be not noticeable, but it could make a difference under other circumstances.

If you want cities that do not have vowels at the beginning *and* end of their name, then:

```
WHERE city not  like '[aeiou]%' AND city not  like '%[aeiou]'
```

or:

```
WHERE city LIKE '[^aeiou]%[^aeiou]'
```

"Miami" does not match these conditions, but "Boston" does.

Answer (score 1):

No. They are not same. 
Here is sample input: xyz, axyz, xyza, axyza, a.

1st query will return: xyz, axyz, xyza. In this 'AND' should be used to get the desired output. Query below will return xyz only.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY
FROM STATION
WHERE city NOT LIKE '[aeiou]%'
   AND city NOT LIKE '%[aeiou]'
```

2nd query will return: xyz, axyz, xyza, a. This is because the condition

```
NOT LIKE '[aeiou]%[aeiou]'
```

means that it should not start AND end with a vowel. Hence axyza is not selected whereas a, axyz and xyza are selected, though they shouldn't have been.